# JQuery .hide() won't hide button suddenly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this a button which a user can click on which adds a comment box at the bottom of the page. My button html looks like this:

```
<input type="button" name="inspection_2895_14045_comment" tabindex="-1" value="+" class="commentBtn" onclick="generateComment('Test', 14045,1, this )">
```

So as you can see it calls a method called `generateComment` which looks like this:

```
    function generateComment(name, id, isInspection, button){

        //get the current button and hide it
        var btn = $("a[name='" + button.name + "'");
        btn.hide();//doesn't work

        var generatedName = '';

        if(isInspection){
            generatedName = "comment_" + id;
        }
        else{
            generatedName = "section_" + id;
        }

        var comment = $('#comments');
        var genHtml = '<div class="bigDataDiv">' +
                      '     <label class="commentBoxLabels">' + name + '</label>' +
                      '     <a href="#" class="comment_close" onclick="removeComment(\'' + button.name + '\',this, event);">x</a>' +
                      '     <textarea rows="4" class="commentBox" name=' + generatedName + ' maxlength="200"></textarea>'
                      '</div>';
        comment.append(genHtml);

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".bigDataDiv").offset().top},
            'slow');
    }
```

All this method does it hide the button, generate the comment div then scroll to the newly created div. This code worked no problem and used to hide the button but now for some reason it doesn't work and the button still shows up

Comment: Do you get an error message in your javascript console?  If so, what is it?

Comment: I doubt that code worked before....

Comment: you're missing a ] in your selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As neokio pointed out, you forgot the closing ], but you are also selecting an anchor tag, when what you want is an input tag.

```
var btn = $("input[name='" + button.name + "']");
```

Comment: We've all been there :)

Comment: So this should do as well :  $(button).hide();

Answer (score 2):

Since button in your generateComment function is a reference to the button you could just use this to set your btn variable:

```
var btn = $(button);
```

Then you don't have to worry about putting strings together to make your selector, or what kind of element the button is.  Your hide should work no matter what that way.

Comment: i like this, will definitely use it in the future

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the closing ] ...

```
var btn = $("a[name='" + button.name + "']");
```

You're also missing a `+` before the final `'</div>';`

Comment: still doesn't seem to work, i'll post what my btn variable looks like

Comment: see note added to answer above

Comment: realized that, I've fixed all those issues and the button still remains there

Comment: if you refresh the code in your post, we can see where you're at

Comment: you're also calling '`<label class="commentBoxLabels">' + name + '</label>'`  .. but there's no such thing as `name`  (oh, yeah there is :)

Comment: the name comes from one of the paramters. Thanks for finding a few hidden problem i hadn't noticed